# JUnit Test return lateinit property <nameOfInstance>has not been initialized on presenter

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, dagger-2

I wanna t create a simple JUnit testing an the test return an error like

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
>   mInstance has not been initialized

my tests I will write in Java. Here is the test class. My presenter and all classes is written in `Kotlin` with `Dagger2` and `RxJava`.

```
public class PhoneNumberPresenterTest {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    private PhoneNumberContract.View view;

    @Inject
    private PhoneNumberPresenter phoneNumberPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        phoneNumberPresenter = new PhoneNumberPresenter(this.view);
    }

    @Test
    public void fetchValidDataShouldLoadIntoView() {
        SendCodeRequest request = new SendCodeRequest(anyString());
        GenericResponse<User> response = new GenericResponse<>();

        when(phoneNumberPresenter.mUserService.sendCode(request))
                .thenReturn(Observable.just(response));

    }
}
```

In My Presenter I do that

```
class PhoneNumberPresenter() : PhoneNumberContract.Handler {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mUserService: UserService

    init {
        Application.mInstance.mComponent.inject(this)
    }
//.....
   mUserService.sendPhoneNumber().....
}
```

In AppComponent class that

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(HttpModule::class, AppModule::class))

interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(presenter: PhoneNumberPresenter)
}
```

And the error of test is that "lateinit property mUserService has not been initialized"

Comment: Please show your Kotlin code where the mInstance property is declared, initialized and accessed.

Comment: Here is the line where the test crash "
    init {
       Application.mInstance.mComponent.inject(this)
    }
" and the Application is an companion object wich extend  MultiDexApplication() , in that class, on onCreate() I initialize the dagger component

Comment: You need to attach code by editing your question, not by posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Dagger for unit testing if I can avoid it because I want to control what's a mock, what's a spy, etc.

You should not use any "Application.mInstance" with Dagger. It seems like you use Dagger before version 2.10 - you should upgrade to the latest and greatest! There is a whole section about Android on https://google.github.io/dagger/android

With Dagger 2.10 and upwards you can inherit from DaggerApplication and then use AndroidInjection.inject() for Activities and @Inject on the constructor for your own classes.

```
public class MyApplication extends DaggerApplication {

    /**
     * This is the same as extending from  MultiDexApplication.
     * @see android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
     */
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this);
    }
}
```

Your activities should look like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

For testing of activities, maybe you should use a TestApplication instead of your real Application class? See https://android.jlelse.eu/testing-your-app-with-dagger-2-c91cdc0860fb for some hints about that.